# Выбрать случайную запись из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с перечнем фруктов (1 фрукт - 1 запись).
Например:

ID | NAME:
1 Яблоко
2 Груша
3 Ананас
4 Банан

С помощью PHP мне нужно выводить рандомный фрукт, я бы использовал такую конструкцию:

```
$randFruit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fruits`  WHERE id = rand(0, **[количество записей в бд]**");
```

Но я не знаю, как узнать количество записей в бд, чтобы установить диапазон для rand?

Comment: А почему ты решил, что количество записей в бд имеет хоть какое-то отношение к id?

Comment: Это у меня так. Понимаю, что может быть не так.

Comment: У тебя это тоже не так.

Comment: Почему? Потому что первый Id 0?

Comment: Нет. Потому что записи **всегда** удаляются. И значение id **всегда** не имеет никакого отношения к количеству записей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT * FROM Fruits ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить код?

Comment: RAND это функция sql  для генерации случайного числа, мы сортируем записи по случайному значению и через limit выбираем только первую

Comment: То есть, RAND() перемешивает все записи?

Comment: Не RAND и не записи. Перемешивает ORDER BY, только не записи, а вывод.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score -1):

Тебе нужно выполнить вложенный запрос 
Попробуй как то так:

```
$randFruit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fruits`  WHERE id = rand(0, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `fruits`));
```

Comment: Это ОЧЕНЬ плохой вариант. В реальной жизни он работать не будет. Попробуй догадаться почему.

Comment: Если бы я знал, то не написал так.
Можно объяснение ?

Comment: Знать заранее не обязательно. ещё можно прийти к нужным выводам с помощью логического мышления. Поэтому я и предложил тебе подумать самостоятельно. id не имеет отношения к количеству записей в БД. В реальной жизни записи удаляются, и вполне мождет быть так, что твой запрос не найдет ни одной записи. Вообще не следует относиться к id как к исчислимой сущности - это приведет к очень большим проблемам. id - это  абстрактный уникальный идентификатор, а не номер по порядку.